# Logstash JSON serialization fails on valid JSON (mapper_parsing_exception)

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

**Given** the following multiline log

```
{
  "code" : 429
}
```

And the following pipeline `logstash.conf`

```
filter { 
    grok {
        match => 
        {
            "message" => 
                [
                    "%{GREEDYDATA:json}"
                ]
        }
    }

    json {
        source => "json"
        target => "json"
    }
}
```

**When** Log is send into logstash through filebeat

**Then** Logstash returns

```
[2018-08-07T10:48:41,067][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"filebeat-to-logstash", :_type=>"doc", :_routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0x2bf7b08d>], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"filebeat-to-logstash", "_type"=>"doc", "_id"=>"trAAFGUBnhQ5nUWmyzVg", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [json]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_state_exception", "reason"=>"Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:3846"}}}}}
```

This is incorrect behavior as the JSON is perfectly valid, how should this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in Logstash `6.3.0` this problem occurs when one tries to serialize JSON on the `"json"` field. Changing this field name to anything else solves this issue.

Since [Elastic JSON filter plugin documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html) does not mention anything about this behaviour and the error message is inaccurate it can be assumed this is a bug.

Bug report has been send: https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/9876